# Map XInput2 devices to sysfs nodes

Tags: linux, sysfs, xinput, evdev

How can I turn an XInput2 device, e.g. as reported by `XIQueryDevice`, into an appropriate `sysfs` node? The device is a generic HID device, handled by the `evdev` input driver.

I know I can get the `name` of the device. I might be able to look at the `Xorg.0.log` and try to find the appropriate log message of when this device was added, hoping that it mentions the `/dev/input/event*` device node associated with that. Or I could look at all input events in `sysfs`, look for one with that name, and hope that the name is unique and identical with the one reported via XInput. But I hope there is a cleaner solution than either of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Device Id using `xinput` command. From that you get can get device node path using `xinput list-props <device id>`. Property 261 is the device node.

Once you have the device node, you can get the sysfs node path using `udevadm info -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n <device node path>)`.

Lazy oneliner is

```
 udevadm info  -q path -n $(xinput list-props `xinput | grep "search term" | awk -F "id=" '{print $2}' | awk  '{print $1}'` | grep "261" | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')
```

`

To do this programmatically you want to call `XIGetProperty` with the deviceid from `XIDeviceInfo` (e.g `XIDeviceInfo->deviceid`), example calling syntax is [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/tree/src/property.c).

To get the sysfs path from the device path, you use `udev_device_new_from_devnum` with stat (as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/gentoo/eudev/blob/master/src/udev/udevadm-util.c)), to make a `udev_device` from the device path and then call `udev_device_get_syspath` with that `udev_device` as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Input devices can have additional properties; `XIListProperties` will enumerate them. On my system at least, one of those properties is "Device Node", which points to the `/dev/input/eventX` device for the device.

Basically, though, `XIQueryDevice` to find the devices, then `XIGetProperty` for the "Device Name" property on each of them. (You'll need some atom interning stuff in there.)

The `xinput` utility ([code here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/tree/src)) can display this information: `xinput list-props $devid` and should serve as a complete example of what to do.